# Use my homepod to hear audio at the drive-in theatre through FM

Tags: homepod

I would like to use my homepod to hear audio at the drive-in theatre.  The theatre uses a local fm transmitter that broadcasts locally within a 500 foot range or so.  Is there a way to enable my phone to receive this signal?  The drive-in does not broadcast over WiFi so it seems the FM apps on the iPhone won't work. Is there another portable device (fm receiver) that would allow me to receive the signal and then transmit it either by wire or wirelessly to the homepod?  I can't seem to find one that will send output wired or wirelessly to another device.

Comment: You could probably do it with a portable FM radio with a headphone jack and appropriate cable and lightning adapter to your iPhone - then Airplay to the HomePod. But I honestly don’t think you will be happy with the results for the effort. There will likely be a small but significant enough delay in lipsync to the movie and probably not sound better than your car speakers. If you have or want to get the parts and try I’ll post more details in an answer.

Comment: Doesn't the car have a standard radio built-in?